# Maven repository and "Android support library", revision 18 for Android Studio 0.2.x

Tags: android-studio

Unable to download "Android support library", revision **18** using **android studio version 0.2.x** and also Maven repository 
Please provide links or steps to download.

Answer (score 0):

Install fresh Android Studio 0.2.x. Upgrade from pre 0.2 doesn't work as mentioned here http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#Updating

Reason is that new Android Studio is shipped with maven repo for serving support libraries.

Alternatively edit build.gradle and replace

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
```

with

```
compile files('/libs/android-support-v4.jar')
```

then copy support jar to libs folder.

Comment: I have this problem on fresh Android Studio 0.2.x.
I'm using Android Studio first time.

Comment: have you tried download any other library? Try 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-asl:0.9.5'. Cleanup .gradle folders in project folder and in your user home folder. Also delete .m2 folder in your user home folder (backup any private jars installed before)

Comment: -robotoaster ok lets check this one too...!!

Comment: i can't download 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-asl:0.9.5' one too.

Comment: please post your build.gradle